# IF, THEN syntax in MySQL with multiple statements

Tags: mysql

I am  fairly new to SQL so I apologize if my code and/or explanation is not clear but please ask me for clarification if something is unclear.

Basically I have a procedure that uses two cursors to assign segmentid values to a flight_times table based on some conditions.  In those conditions I will either 1) assign a segmentID then fetch the next record from the segments cursor, 2) assign a null value then fetch the next row from the flight_times cursor, or 3) if the flightdate and flight number do not match, fetch the next row from the segments cursor.

The problem I am having is that I cannot get the IF statements to accept multiple statements without saying I have a syntax error.  For example, after I try to assign a null value, I cannot then fetch another record from the times cursor.  I would appreciate any assistance anyone may offer on what i am doing wrong here.  I have reviewed the MySQL manual and it does indicate that I am allowed to have multiple statements

```
CREATE PROCEDURE write_flight_times(OUT f_date DATE, OUT f_no VARCHAR(20), OUT s_segid INT, OUT s_iataid CHAR(3),
OUT ft_date DATE, OUT ft_no VARCHAR(20), OUT ft_iataid CHAR(3))

BEGIN

DECLARE var_no_more_rows BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE var_no_more_rows1 BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;

DECLARE cur_segments CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT flightdate, flightno, segmentid, iataid
    FROM flights f JOIN segments s ON f.flightid = s.flights_flightid
    ORDER BY flightdate, flightno, segmentid;

DECLARE cur_times CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT flights_flightdate, flights_flightno, a.iataid
    FROM temp_flight_times tft JOIN airports a ON a.icaoid = tft.airports_icaoid
    ORDER BY flights_flightdate, flights_flightno, depttime;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND

SET var_no_more_rows := TRUE;
SET var_no_more_rows1 := TRUE;

OPEN cur_segments;

loop_segments:
LOOP
    FETCH cur_segments INTO f_date, f_no, s_segid, s_iataid;
    IF var_no_more_rows THEN
       CLOSE cur_segments;
       LEAVE loop_segments;
    END IF;

    OPEN cur_times;

    loop_times:
    LOOP
        FETCH cur_times INTO ft_date, ft_no, ft_iataid;
            IF var_no_more_rows1 THEN
               CLOSE cur_times;
               LEAVE loop_times;
            END IF;

            IF (f_date = ft_date AND f_no = ft_no) THEN
                IF s_iataid = ft_iataid THEN
                    s_segid;
                ELSE
                    NULL;
                    FETCH cur_times INTO ft_date, ft_no, ft_iataid;
                END IF
            ELSE
                FETCH cur_segments INTO f_date, f_no, s_segid, s_iataid;
            END IF) AS segmentid
     END LOOP loop_times;
  END LOOP loop_segments;  
  END$$
```

Comment: Does the code you presented give an error?

Comment: Sorry, yes error 1064 syntax error.  it is on the semicolon in the if statement right after the s_segid

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't have multiple "not found" handlers in a stored proc, so when the inner loop gets a "not found" condition, the outer loop's "no rows found" variable is also set to true, terminating the outer loop.

The solution is to split the logic into two stored procs - one for each cursor - and call the inner stored proc from the outer one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will split them but right now my error is in the if statement itself--see comment above for error